# Azure AutoML pipeline -Batch scoring fails with "DriverException: Job failed with There is no succeeded mini batch item returned from run()

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines, azure-auto-ml

**While running automl parallel run with tabulardataset** ,

azureml_common.parallel_run.exception.NoResultToAppendError: There is no succeeded mini batch item returned from run()

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your scoring script may not have a correct return line in it's run method. Could you share your scoring file?
For additional context, AutoML jobs don't produce a scoring file that works with batch inferencing, it has to be created manually as per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-batch-scoring-script).